# Creating and populating an empty Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm actually learning swift in order to develop iOS apps. I'd like, as an exercise, to create and populate an empty array, that would be filled by using a textfield and a button on the storyboard.

```
var arr = []

// When button is pressed : 
arr.append(textfield.text)
```

XCode tells me that the append method is not a method of NSArray. So I have used the addObject one, but it is still not correct as the arr variable contains nil.

So here are my three questions :

Is it possible to create an empty array, and if so, how to populate it ?

Sometimes, in my ViewController, when I create a non-empty array, the append method is apparently not valid, and I don't understand why..

Finally, why even though I use the syntax :

```
var arr = [1] // For example
```

The arr object is NSArray object and not a NSMutableArray object, making it impossible to add/remove any object that is contained in it?

I hope my questions are clear, if not I'll upload more code of what I'm trying to build,

thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 3):

Try to define your array as a String array, like this:

```
var arr: [String] = []
```

And then append to your list, either by:

```
arr.append("the string")
```

or

```
arr += ["the string"]
```

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I was thinking reading the Swift guide about collection types 5 minutes ago, I didn't remember that arrays were type inferred, hence I need to specify the type of the empty array in order to modify it later. Thank you @eightx2 !

Answer (score 1):

Empty array can be created using the following syntax.

```
var emptyArray = [String]()
emptyArray.append("Hi")
```

see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

You can use following also to add elements to your array.

```
//append - to add only one element
emptyArray.append("Hi")

//To add multiple elements
emptyArray += ["Hello", "How r u"]
emptyArray.extend(["am fine", "How r u"])

//Insert at specific index
emptyArray.insert("Who r u", atIndex: 1)

//To insert another array objects
var array1 = ["who", "what", "why"]
emptyArray.splice(array1, atIndex: 1)
```

Comment: Yeah, I read the guide right after posting my question and realized arrays where one-type collection objects, hence needing specifying the type for empty ones, since it cannot be inferred by Swift, thanks for your elaborate answer @Dev